# Append Query String to IIS Rewrite Map

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7

I have a ReWrite Map and I would like to append any query parameters in the requested URL to the rewritten URL.

For instance:

- /page/abc/ ---> /index.cfm?page=abc **(works)**
- /page/abc/?param1=111 ---> /index.cfm?page=abc&param1=111 **(doesn't work)**
- /page/abc/?param3=333&param4=444 ---> /index.cfm?page=abc&param3=333&param4=444 **(doesn't work)**

My web.config is:

```
[...]
<rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Rewrite rule1 for SiteMapEngine">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{SiteMapEngine:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
</rules>
[...]
```

Answer (score 26):

**Short answer:**

Use PATH_INFO server variable instead of REQUEST_URI, as you do not want to include the query string in the matching.

**Full explanation:**

This has caught me out before - basically it is a subtlety of using [Rewrite Maps](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/469/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module/) in the IIS URL Rewrite Module.

In your case, SiteMapEngine will be a static key-value list of URLs:

```
<rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="SiteMapEngine" defaultValue="">
            <add key="/page/abc/" value="/index.cfm?page=abc" />
            ...
        </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>
    ...
</rewrite>
```

The {SiteMapEngine:{REQUEST_URI}} condition in your rule checks whether there is a key in this rewrite map matching the REQUEST_URI server variable:

```
{REQUEST_URI} = /page/abc/?param1=111
```

Notice that this variable includes the query string - it therefore fails to find a matching key.

Instead, use the PATH_INFO server variable, which is the **equivalent of REQUEST_URI but without the query string**:

```
{PATH_INFO} = /page/abc/
```

So the correct rule is:

```
<rule name="Rewrite rule1 for SiteMapEngine">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{SiteMapEngine:{PATH_INFO}}" pattern="(.+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Brilliant explanation. To fully answer the original question you also need to remember to add appendQueryString="true" to the action tag.

Comment: Nine years later, still a great answer. Editing the files directly, I made the PATH_INFO change to my rule, didn't work. Made an additional change which killed the website entirely. Undid the second change only, leaving the PATH_INFO change and it magically worked. Not sure if it forced a refresh or what, but it fixed an issue I was unaware of that had been plaguing our marketing people for years.

Answer (score 14):

I'll be damned if I can find a reference for this, but it's my understanding that in some versions of IIS {REQUEST_URI} comes back without it's query string, and will be empty entirely if rewriting is enabled.

You should be able to use {PATH_INFO} instead.

This bug report (against Drupal!) is the issue you're describing, I think: http://drupal.org/node/298016

There's a hotfix from Microsoft, but I haven't tried it: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954946

Comment: Oh God how this just saved my life.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my rule. It seems to work as expected:

```
<rule name="Insert index.cfm" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.cfm/{PATH_INFO}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```